# Can't check if a role is granted

Tags: php, symfony, twig, user-roles

I've to set dynamic role to an user when he logs in, so I've created a service `LoginSuccessHanlder` with this function on login success :

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token) {
    $response = null;

    $user = $this->token->getToken()->getUser();
    $poste = $request->get('_poste');
    $user->addRole('ROLE_'.strtoupper($poste));
    $this->em->persist($user);
    $this->em->flush();
    if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('homepage'));
        $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('poste', $poste));
    }

    return $response;
}
```

So here, I add a new role to the user thanks to a field in the login form `_poste`
. Once I'm logged in I should be able to do :

```
{% if is_granted("ROLE_FLEX") %}
    message
{% endif %}
```

But there is no message

But if I do this :

```
{{ dump(app.user.roles) }}
```

I have in the array the role `ROLE_FLEX`, why I can't check the role with `is_granted` function ? What did I missed ?

For information, I'm using FOSUserBundle

**EDIT**

I remove the role each time that the user logout so when a user logout he doesn't have the `ROLE_FLEX` anymore but the role will be added if he check this role on log in. Basically the user has a role for each session

Comment: Can you show the `addRole` function code?

Comment: @i.am.michiel the `addRole` function is provided by the FOSUserBundle

Comment: Are the roles persisted? On every request, the FOSUserBundle reloads the user and roles from the database (or whatever your provider is).

Comment: only as test, if the user do a logout then relog into the system, the message appear (the check go fine)?

Comment: @i.am.michiel Yes, I've checked in my db when I log in and the role are persisted

Comment: @Matteo No the message still doesn't appear

Comment: Use the web debug toolbar to look at your security session data.  Is ROLE_FLEX in it?  Symfony actually uses a security token when checking permissions.  The token basically has a copy of the roles.  I can understand have a problem within the same request.  But logging out then logging back in really should work.

Comment: Also, why are you using $this->token->getToken() instead of just the passed $token? Copy paste error?

Comment: @Cerad The thing is that I remove the role when the user logout because I need to set a different role that depends on a select on the form login, but this shouldn't impact on the user when he is logged in.
I've found another solution, but thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RoleVoter` class that is used by the Symfony Security layer when you pass a role to the `is_granted()` function reads the roles from the token and not the user object. This means that you will have to update the token accordingly too.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem ! I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713802/symfony-2-3-how-do-i-refresh-the-authenticated-user-from-the-database) question to refresh the token

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found was to create my own function to check If a user have a specific role :

```
public function isGranted($role)
{
    return in_array($role, $this->getRoles());
}
```

now I can use `{% if app.user.isGranted("ROLE_FLEX") %}`

Comment: Just make a note that you are bypassing the security system when you do this.  If you ever decide to use things like voters and what not then you will run into trouble.

Comment: @Cerad I didn't found other solution for now  since I remove the role when the user logout